# Safari renders text input boxes and textarea differently on iOS and OS X

Tags: html, ios, macos, input, safari

I discovered Safari 6 on the Mac renders text input boxes and textarea boxes differently from Safari on iOS 6.

OS X:
[image: Safari 6 on OS X ML]

iPad:
[image: iPad running iOS 6]

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
        <body>
            Name:<br />
            <input type="text" size="65" />
            <br /><br />

            Comments: <br />
            <textarea rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
            <br />

            <input type="submit" />
        </body>
</html>
```

Questions: 
1) Is this a bug? If so, I'll report it to Apple. But what platform is at fault?
2) How do I work around these issues? They need to be consistent - both input boxes and textarea needs to be the same size on both platforms.

Thanks!!

Edit: It may just be the textarea that's not the same size, although it's hard to tell.

Comment: it would be easier to tell if you put 60-65 char in each field so you could tell what is going on, both of those values should be number of chars.

Comment: Interesting. On iOS, size = cols - they are the same width. But not on OS X.